# I don't see any output on entering the following command:select inet_server_addr();

Tags: postgresql

when I enter the command:- 
select inet_server_addr();
I get an output something like this:

```
 inet_server_addr 
------------------
 ::1
(1 row)
```

Does this mean my postgresql server is not running?How do I fix that??

Comment: it means localhost for IP v6

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html:

> inet_server_addr()    inet    address of the local connection

`::1` means you are connected on PIv6 localhost

you can use protocol version explicitly:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -h ::1 -U vao -d mon
psql (9.3.14)
mon=# select inet_server_addr(),inet_client_addr();
 inet_server_addr | inet_client_addr
------------------+------------------
 ::1              | ::1
(1 row)

mon=# \q
-bash-4.2$ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U vao -d mon
psql (9.3.14)
mon=# select inet_server_addr(),inet_client_addr();
 inet_server_addr | inet_client_addr
------------------+------------------
 127.0.0.1        | 127.0.0.1
(1 row)
```

Comment: How can I get that to become default when I just type psql <database-name> ?